# SharePoint 64bit or 32bit

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

Is it ok to have 32bit dev and test environments with SharePoint? The reason that I am asking is because in my experience most productive large scale MOSS implementations are 64bit.

I work for a company now who have very little experience with SharePoint, and I would like to give them the best advice possible, that is to try and keep the dev, test and production environments the same.

Is this a good recommendation, or does it really not make any differance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the servers are going to be 64bit then at the very least your staging/testing servers should be, even if your devs stick to x86.

One thing to bear in mind though is that SharePoint 2010 will be 64bit only when it ships, so if they are planning to upgrade at some point they may want to roll out x64 now.

Comment: We had a consultant suggest the same thing on a rebuild of our environment.  Go ahead and make the servers 64-bit to make the upgrade to SharePoint 2010 easier.  Also agree with making dev/qa match prod where possible - reduces the liklihood of nasty surprises when implementing in production.

Comment: Steven thanks for the input, can you share any personal experiences of things going wrong because of environment differances?

Comment: Nothing SharePoint related but developing on x86, building for "Any CPU" can have issues if you are relying on 3rd party components (or even some MS libraries that are only x86), using PInvokes (mis-casting IntPtr) etc. Generally they're not critical issues, but if you have the opportunity to put the devs on the same platform then it makes sense, although I wouldn't consider it to be essential.

Comment: Aonther thing worth a mention is that the integration between 64bit versions of IE and office 64bit applications is very problematic in terms of opening office documents directly from inside of SharePoint 2010. Running SharePoint 2010 on server 2008 and Office 2010, go for the 32bit version of office and of IE - otherwise you risk days of pain like I have just had trying to resolve errors. The error I was receiving was 'cannot open the file for editing' mentioned here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/36072eec-59fa-4640-bf91-40be30577ad4